# Craft 4 slow on DDEV OSX Monterey

Tags: craft4, speed, ddev

Set up my first Craft 4 install locally on DDEV on OSX Monterey, followed the install guide here https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/installation.html#quick-start

Seems to be working fine except its slow, the admin takes 5-10 seconds to load a page.

Turned off dev mode, no change.

Any pointers for how to troubleshoot this and get it up to speed?

Thanks.

Edit: It works perfectly and very fast when uploaded to the server, so the install itself is fine I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I’m using Ventura, but I don’t recall Craft being slow on Monterey.

Did you allocate enough resources in Docker? (Settings button in the top right > Resources.)

I currently have:

CPUs: 5 / Memory: 10gb / Swap:2gb / Disk image size: 136gb

Comment: Thanks @Mitrol, I just tried adjusting this but it did not help.  I'm at CPUs: 4 / Memory: 5gb / Swap:2gb / Disk image size: 360gb

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue and finally [enabled mutagen](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/install/performance/#filesystem-performance):

```
   ddev stop    
   ddev config global --mutagen-enabled
   ddev start
```

This took me from a loading time of 10s to less than 50ms. The only issue I've found is that it takes updates about 20s to propagate.